# In the debugger, can we make `q` choose a given restart?

Tags: common-lisp, slime

I am trying a program. On error, I get into the debugger with several custom restarts. The first one retries the operation (and thus does nothing), the fourth one is the one to quit correctly. Pressing `q` leads to a memory error.

How can the developer make sure programatically that when the user presses `q`, the right restart is called ? And not the one bound to `q` that leads to a memory error ? Is that possible ? 
That may be too specific to the library I'm trying, or totally the wrong approach.

I only found that `q` is `sldb-quit` and that it "invoke[s] a restart which restores to a known program state". `q` doesn't call the first restart. What does it do ? Is it possible to make it call a given restart ?

thanks

Comment: Should this be on the emacs SE? I’m not really sure. I don’t know what `q` (hence this is not an answer) does but my first guess is that it looks at the list of restarts and picks the first (ie dynamically topmost on the stack) restart which meets some criteria for meaning “quit”, so eg I would guess that the abort to reply restart would meet these but maybe not be the top. Certainly there are other shortcut keys to search for specific restarts in sldb (maybe `a` for abort and another for retry?)

Comment: note that I'm asking from the library's developer perspective (I'll rephrase my question): the developer defines several restarts, and he faces the problem that if the user hits `q`, as usual, the program has a memory error. He would like his restart to be called by default. The user can still choose the fourth restart manually. That may be the wrong approach, the wrong question though!. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can help, I can't test right now: https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Other-configurables.html#g_t_002aSLDB_002dQUIT_002dRESTART_002a

Comment: Sounds like something that `unwind-protect` could help fix? If not, you could try to add a `handler-bind` to catch all errors, then use `find-restart` to see if your restart is available in that context and finally use `invoke-restart` to programmatically chose that restart. Note that the debugger will not show up though. To give a better answer, we might need more details. Why the user have choices when they're is only one good answer?